# i'm unable to export html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, excel, export-to-excel

i'm using `tableexport.js` plugin for `html` table  export.

i have a `html` table like this.

```
<table id="all_category_data">
 ..
...
.....
</table>
```

i'n `javascript`  i'm doing something like this

```
$('#all_category_data').tableExport({ type: 'excel', escape: 'false' });
```

**here is jsfiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/2kt4u8hn/3/

please help me thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport#download-and-setup) clearly states:

> To use this plugin, include the jQuery library, FileSaver.js script,
>   and TableExport.js plugin before the closing  tag of your HTML
>   document.

In your code, you didn't include jquery and fileserver.js. See below for a working variant of your fiddle.

```js
$('#all_category_data').tableExport({ type: 'excel', escape: 'false' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e241bd15288553341b3629f5d1e0bc7aaa8a7a38/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/3.3.9/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 id="all_category_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>User Belongs to</th>
            <th>Total Work Assigned</th>
            <th>Not Emailed</th>
            <th>Email Sent</th>
            <th>Response Recieved</th>
            <th>Interested</th>
            <th>Not Interested</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>vidyaranyapura</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bangalore</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>karnataka</td>
            <td><span style="color:#3498db;">Company</span></td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>otherstates</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>global</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>business</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>software</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>placement</td>
            <td><span style="color:#3498db;">Company</span></td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>training</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>realestate</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>techparks</td>
            <td><span style="color:#3498db;">Company</span></td>
            <td>117</td>
            <td>117</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>tienetwork</td>
            <td><span style="color:#3498db;">Company</span></td>
            <td>2488</td>
            <td>2487</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>linkedin</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>facebook</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>individual</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>schools</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>colleges</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>clubs</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>temples</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hospital</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>financial</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>marketing</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>products</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>mahesh</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>postmail</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>landline</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>email</td>
            <td><span style="color:#3498db;">Company</span></td>
            <td>6932</td>
            <td>6932</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>whatsapp</td>
            <td><span style="color:red;">Not Assigned</span></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:#4A148C;font-size:33px;">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>9765 <span style="color:red;font-size:11px;">Total work assigned</span></td>
            <td>9564 <span style="color:red;font-size:11px;">Not Emailed</span></td>
            <td>0 <span style="color:red;font-size:11px;">Email Sent</span></td>
            <td>0 <span style="color:red;font-size:11px;">Response Recieved</span></td>
            <td>0 <span style="color:red;font-size:11px;"> Interested</span></td>
            <td>0 <span style="color:red;font-size:11px;">Not Interested</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: at mr @Nehal J Wani, this is the best `answer` regarding `tableexport.js` , i have struggled a lot but `script include is very different that does not work  `

Comment: What do you mean by 'script include is very different that does not work' ? I have posted a working snippet in the answer.

Comment: it is there on git hub include script in this manner `<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
   <!-- <script src="Contents/tableExport.js"></script>
        <script src="Contents/jquery.base64.js"></script>
            <script src="Contents/html2canvas.js"></script>
                <script src="Contents/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script>
                    <script src="Contents/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
                   <script src="Contents/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>-->`